# Temperature effect on metal implant

Tags: material-science

How much would a metal implant (rod inside the tibia bone) be affected inside the body by the temperature outside the body. How would i find out the temperature of the implant considering that homoeostasis keeps the body at 37C? The metal I'm thinking about is a shape memory alloy called Nickel-Titanium. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the implant is deep in the body, it will not change temperature that much. What are your temperature limits of concern?

Comment: @Jon Custer Isn't the tibia the shin bone that you can feel through only a thin layer of skin on most people? In that case the implant may not be deep within the body.

Comment: Inside a main bone in your body is deep inside for all practical purposes. Your pinky finger, not so much. If the inside of your tibia is deviating dramatically from normal body temperature you are in big trouble and need immediate medical care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body keeps metal implants at body temperature.  An external temperature change severe enough to penetrate to the implant would require your body to, in effect, shut down.  In the absence of such dramatic temperature changes, the nickel titanium will be maintained at the temperature of the surrounding bone.  Its advantage over other metals is that it is slightly elastic, like bone, and acts like bone when there is strain as a result of stress that deforms the bone.

Although [nickel titanium alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_titanium#Biocompatible_and_biomedical_applications) (nitinol) has been used for many bio-medical purposes, [nickel allergy](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/nickel-allergy/home/ovc-20267453) may appear in humans who have been sensitized to the metal through repeated contact.  This propensity is controlled by [passivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitinol_biocompatibility), a process that isolates corrosive substances from the surface of the biomedical prosthesis or device.  The surface oxidation layer created by passivation should be robust enough to avoid micro cracks during flexing that might expose the nickel in [nitinol](http://www2.lbl.gov/ritchie/Library/PDF/2012_Robertson_IMR_Mechanical.pdf) to your body.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Ernie. I was thinking about an IM rod that was proposed by a research paper where the nitinol module in the rod expands to create friction. They said that you could cool it to make the nitinol contract and easily remove the rod. But how would you cool the rod inside the leg (with an ice pack maybe?) and if it is that easy then surely weather changes will effect it as well.

Comment: the research paper i mentioned is here http://www.intechopen.com/books/biomedical-engineering-from-theory-to-applications/orthopaedic-modular-implants-based-on-shape-memory-alloys

Comment: wikipedia mentioned that nitinol changes shape for temperatures between 0 and 40C as well

Comment: @J.Doe : You could cool the nitinol appliance by conduction.  If the cold pack were attached to the nitinol by a heat-conductive wire, heat in the nitinol would flow out to the cold pack.  This could be facilitated by opening the leg, which would be necessary anyway so that the nitinol rod could be extracted.  As long as the leg were closed, weather would have no effect on the nitinol, as there would be no heat conduction between the nitinol and the outside weather.  Circulation in the body's soft tissues maintain temperature unless there is conduction to a cold heat sink outside the leg.

Answer (score 0):

I have 5 or 6 ribs that are braced with titanium plates on my left side back.  It seems as though that part of my back feels cold in the cold winter air.  Even inside where the temperature is 65-68.